# Could not install or assign error using Unity AR Foundation and ArCore

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, arcore

I just setup a new project using Unity 2019.3.15, Ar Foundation 3.1.3 and AR Core 3.1.3, but for some reason **sometimes** Unity throws me this errors when i hit play:

```
Could not install or assign any package with id . Check if there are any other errors in the console and make sure they are corrected before trying again.

NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
UnityEditor.XR.Management.Metadata.XRPackageMetadataStore.QueueLoaderRequest (UnityEditor.XR.Management.Metadata.XRPackageMetadataStore+LoaderAssignmentRequest req) (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.xr.management@3.2.10/Editor/Metadata/XRPackageMetadata.cs:665)
UnityEditor.XR.Management.Metadata.XRPackageMetadataStore.RebuildCache () (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.xr.management@3.2.10/Editor/Metadata/XRPackageMetadata.cs:374)
System.Reflection.MonoMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, System.Reflection.BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) (at <437ba245d8404784b9fbab9b439ac908>:0)
Rethrow as TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
System.Reflection.MonoMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, System.Reflection.BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) (at <437ba245d8404784b9fbab9b439ac908>:0)
System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke (System.Object obj, System.Object[] parameters) (at <437ba245d8404784b9fbab9b439ac908>:0)
System.Delegate.DynamicInvokeImpl (System.Object[] args) (at <437ba245d8404784b9fbab9b439ac908>:0)
System.MulticastDelegate.DynamicInvokeImpl (System.Object[] args) (at <437ba245d8404784b9fbab9b439ac908>:0)
System.Delegate.DynamicInvoke (System.Object[] args) (at <437ba245d8404784b9fbab9b439ac908>:0)
UnityEditor.EditorApplication.Internal_CallUpdateFunctions () (at <a20a50bbfaff4193bf6ba6b262f9a71f>:0)
```

Any ideas on what can be happening or where can I look to see if im doing something wrong?

Regards